# faster way to join on modified fields in postgres

Tags: postgresql, join

I have a particularly annoying case in which I need to join two rather large tables (one ~270k rows, the other ~1.1M rows) on multiple fields (with an OR condition) that need text transformation before the join.

Relevant part of the query:

```
FULL JOIN fbo_all_opportunity_detail fbo 
ON replace(split_part(table1.col::text, ' '::text, 2), '-'::text, ''::text) = table2.col 
OR btrim(replace(table1.col2::text, '-'::text, ''::text)) = table2.col2
```

Unfortunately this method is extremely slow.

One method I have considered is creating a new temp table that runs a replace/split_part on the relevant tables so that I could join on a field without modifying on the fly. But these databases update regularly, so I would need to repeat the cleaning process every time I join, which kind of defeats the purpose.

Are there other methods for accomplishing this I am missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Even if you had indices on the join columns, the string function calls you are making might preclude the use of an index anyway.  If you have a frequent need to join these tables, then one option would be to maintain indexed join columns in the two tables.

Comment: You can create indexes with formulas in Postgres.

Comment: I had no idea; will take a look at this as an option; thanks much

Comment: In addition to the function-based index, have you tried splitting the joins and then doing a union?

Comment: Hambone -- that's going to be my next try; so basically I would do 2 left joins, union them, then dedupe with a group by, right?